# Azure AD Graph API Group Search

Tags: c#, linq, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have an office365 account with active directory on azure.
I am making a search feature that queries our Azure AD with the given search term. Since the Graph API only supports .StartsWith(string) LINQ queries, I have to pull in all groups then query that collection with my search term.

I am using the 'Get Group members' function from [this demo](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/Program.cs) as a guide to make my search function.

Here is my code:

```
public List<myModel> SearchGroups(string term)
    {
        List<myModel> returnList = new List<myModel>();

       //my service root uri
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(serviceRootURL);

        //create the client and get authorization
        ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

        //get collection of IGroup
        IPagedCollection<IGroup> groups = adClient.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result;

        //do while loop because groups are returned in paged list...
        do
        {
            List<IGroup> directoryObjects = groups.CurrentPage.ToList();

            //get groups that contain the search term
            foreach (IGroup item in directoryObjects.Where(x=>x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())))
            {
                returnList.Add(new myModel(item as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group));          
            }
            //get next page of results
            groups = groups.GetNextPageAsync().Result;

        } while (groups.MorePagesAvailable); //also tried while(groups != null) same issue

        return returnList;
    }
```

If I let it run, the code gets hung up and never returns anything and if I pause it, it is usually stuck on this line

```
groups = groups.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
```

If I put a break point and step through the code, it works perfectly fine so I am thinking it is an issue with the async methods. I just have no experience with async methods and the graph api docs are not that great in my opinion so I am stuck.

Using: ASP.NET MVC, C#, azure active directory Graph API, Web API

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.Result` calls on async methods to force synchronicity.  How much of an impact would it be to make your method `async` and use `await groups.GetNextPageAsync()`?

Comment: @EdgySwingsetAcid this method is on an API controller (I create an instance of my API controller in my normal MVC controller and call the method that way) Would this mean I have to make my regular MVC controller async as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use .Result() it is very prone to deadlocks! In this instance just use the await keyword for your async calls. If you go with async programming you should make the whole call async though. trying to make something async, synchronous is a bad practice